# Laravel multitenancy com um BD só para usuários

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, multi-tenancy, laravel-5.6

Tenho pesquisado sobre **Saas** e **Multi-tenancy** mas tem pouco material em português. Vi que é possível fazer um banco de dados para cada empresa, mas a minha dúvida é:

Da pra fazer um sistema web único para todos os clientes(usando PHP+Laravel+MySQL) com um `Banco de dados` pra cada empresa MAS fazer um `Banco de dados` só de "`empresas`"(contendo uma tabela "`users`" com os campos de `empresa`, `usuário`, `senha`, e `bd_empresa`) usando ESSE BD de `empresa` somente para verificar o login e se os dados estiverem certos logar na aplicação usando o BD daquela empresa?

Não sei se consegui deixar claro, espero que sim.

Comment: Sua pergunta parece bastante clara, mas também muito ampla. Não sei até onde a comunidade poderá de fato ajudar nesse caso. De modo geral acredito que a sua proposta é viável sim. Na prática podem haver alguns desafios (acho que mais conceituais do que técnicos) que deverão ser tratados especifica e individualmente.

Comment: Dá sim, eu não uso e nem tenho conhecimento em frameworks PHP, faço tudo na unha, em PDO, mas no meu sistema é basicamente assim, cada empresa tem um banco de dados específico, e compartilham de um banco de dados comum, no banco específico, contem as tabelas de cada uma, e no banco em comum contem informações de acesso público e exclusivo do sistema, tanto para login, quanto para exatamente da mesma forma buscar o banco de cada uma. 
No momento em que a empresa executa o login, faz a busca pelo BD dela, e essa informação é passada para o metodo construtor da classe

Answer (score 0):

Tem como fazer sim e tem varias abordagens.

1 -  Usar a biblioteca multi-tenant

https://github.com/hyn/multi-tenant

2 - Fazer um clase que vai servir de middleware e sempre fazer as requisições no banco da empresa correta.

3 - Distribuir a aplicação e deixar um serviço responsável por gerenciar os bancos de dados e suas consultas

de qualquer forma vai muito do que você precisa fazer

Answer (score 0):

Eu tenho dois sistemas SaaS desenvolvidos em Laravel, e utilizo um único banco de dados.

Para a separação dos dados por empresa, todas as tabelas possuem a chave estrangeira referenciando a tabela de empresa contratante.

Para auxiliar o código, na verdade de forma bem transparente, utilizo este pacote que usa traits para filtrar sempre pela empresa que o usuário autenticado pertence:

https://github.com/torzer/awesome-landlord

Existem ainda outras alternativas que trabalham com a solução de vários bancos de dados, uma por tenant, e também que permitem segregar e gerenciar os tenants por subdomínio, as mais robustas que analisei para usar estas abordagens, em relação à estabilidade e contínuo desenvolvimento são:

- Laravel Tenancy (antigo Hyn Tenancy) - https://tenancy.dev/
- Spatie Laravel Multitenancy - https://github.com/spatie/laravel-multitenancy
- Tenancy for Laravel - https://tenancyforlaravel.com/